# Background color of the main content on the html page disappears

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

It just makes me go mad. I can't realize what the problem is. Please have a look at the pixeli.ca/glass. There is a home page that looks good - white background of the main content and looks good. But all the other pages don't have white background so they look not the way they should look. All the pages have the same style sheet and the same layout elements taken from 960.gs framework. It's just some kind of mystery there. What I need is to make all page look like the home page - having white background.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look on the home page, the last element inside the `<div class="container_8">` tag is another tag called `<div class="clearfix"></div>`.  This is probably a tag designed to bring the height of the container_8  all the way below all the contents.  Add that tag at the end of the container_8 div and see if that fixes it.

I just tested it for you in Firefox.  Adding the clearfix worked.  So you need to change your code to something like

```
<div class="container_8">
    *lots of content here*
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Good luck!